# Remove 'also post on Facebook' button on Facebook Comment plugin

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-comments

I'm using the [Facebook comment embed plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) to let users comment on my page, but I really hate the 'also post on Facebook' radio button. I don't want users to post it on Facebook because it links back to my webpage.

You see, my page lives as a web view on a native mobile app, so the URL with the web view isn't really set up to be visited outside the app.

I checked the docs for a way to disable the 'also post on Facebook' button, but no luck. The plugin creates an iframe, so I can't just hide it with CSS.

I'm wondering if anyone's found more advanced settings for the plugin, or maybe even a hack for hiding that option inside an external iframe.

Thanks!